# how to check if the listView is empty

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, is-empty

Im creating a windows form and I have 2 problems

1. I want to enable the button as soon as i add item in listView otherwise
   disable it if its empty
2. assuming that i have already added item in listview. how can i get the totalprice of all the item and put it in the label as soon as the item added? thanks.

this is the code is use to compute the total price of all item in the listview

```
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    For Each itemRow As ListViewItem In Me.lvOrder.Items

        total += Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.SubItems(2).Text)

    Next
```

sorry i cant put image for better understanding because i need 10 reputation to post an image.

Comment: what about `Me.lvOrder.Items.Count()`

Comment: @un-lucky I try it but it did not work. im want to enable the button as soon as i add item in listview otherwise disable if empty. but I appreciate that you reply. thanks

Comment: Find the code that is adding to the listview, and do your test there.

Comment: `Count` "it did not work"?! It has to work: keeps track of all the items in the list. The only situation where it cannot be used is when the list is null (what never happens with the items of a `ListView`). Apparently you haven't understood un-lucky's proposal; why not asking? rather than concluding such an arbitrary nonsense? Not knowing is not bad (when wanting to learn); but making decisions/assessments on account of such a lack of knowledge might be bad.

Comment: @mort I already did but it did not work fine. but when i try it on gridview its working fine because of the rowAdded event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something as simple as this should do what you want:

```
btnXXX.Enabled = (lvOrder.Items.Count > 0)
```

You just need to make sure you are doing this in the appropriate event(s). or when you add or remove items

Answer (score 2):

To find Sum in C#:

```
var sum = this.listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
              .ToList().Select(item => int.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text))
              .Sum();
```

or in VB

```
Dim sum = listView1.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem).ToList() _
                    .Select(Function(item) Integer.Parse(item.SubItems(2).Text)) _
                    .Sum()
```

To check if the listview has items in C#

```
this.Button1.Enabled= (this.listView1.Items.Count > 0 );
```

Or in VB

```
Me.Button1.Enabled= (Me.listView1.Items.Count > 0 )
```

Comment: thank you for replying. I do already have the code for finding the sum. what i want to know is how to put the sum in label as soon as i add item in the listview.

Comment: @JarobeBernardo Every where you add item to listview, you can calculate sum. and then `Me.Label1.Text= sum.ToString()`

Comment: i do want to vote this. but i need 15 reputation to vote.

Comment: I already did. is there a listview event like rowAdded event in gridview ?

Comment: @JarobeBernardo No there is not such event, instead, you can do your job where you add items.